# Manhwa/manga where female lead tries to change the hero of the story

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead is an elementalist and forms a team of her own and goes to various labyrinths.  The female lead tries to support the hero (main character) of the story secretly and provides him money and various treasures that are found on his mission. Later the place main character works is found to be sold by the female lead and he tries to find her.  The main character is having red eyes which are said to be very dangerous and attracts all the fire spirits but ended up taming the strongest fire spirit.

It was in full color. The female lead had golden hair.

The story in the beginning has the daughter being experimented on by her father and also her grandfather is some kind of great wizard. When her grandfather visits her, the female lead begs for her grandfather to save her. Also she has been investigating her mother's death after being with her maternal family.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters or the places they visit?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: The story was in full color and the hair of fl is golden

Comment: The story in the beginning have the daughter being experimented on by her father and also her grandfather is some kind of great wizard.The female lead when her grandfather visits begs for her grandfather to save her. Also she has been investigating her mother death after being with her maternal family.

Answer (score 2):

This is *[The Hero's Savior](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-heros-savior)*.

> **After years of torture at the hands of her own father, young elementalist** Ariadne Eldier sees her chance to escape when her mother’s untimely death prompts a visit from **her grandfather, a powerful archmage**. Once whisked away to safety, Aria begins her plans to not only distribute an elixir for the contamination plaguing the land, but also **save the protagonist and prevent this novel’s tragic ending**. But with her own fated death looming, will Aria be able to become the hero this tale needs?

[image: Cover image]

The synopsis covers much of the details; the female lead begs her maternal grandfather to free her from her father's torture and human experiments. He was also the cause of her mother's death, in pursuit of a magical elixir.

She uses her knowledge of the events of the story to help the male lead from the shadows; he's a slave and she purchases him, ensuring he has access to education and various artifacts that are found within the story in advance. As you mention, he has red eyes and is a fire elementalist, which also attracts fire spirits to him, frequently with disastrous results for other people.

[image: Red eyes]